# Outlook Reply Macro Not Displaying Images/Allowing 'Discard' mail option

Tags: vba, outlook

I am currently using the following macro to reply to messages:

```
Sub Reply()

    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem
    Dim recip As Recipient
    Dim allRecips As String

    Set origEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    Set replyEmail = origEmail.Reply
    
    For Each recip In origEmail.Recipients
    If (Len(allRecips) > 0) Then allRecips = allRecips & "; "
    allRecips = allRecips & recip.Address
    Next

    replyEmail.To = origEmail.SenderEmailAddress & "; " & allRecips
    replyEmail.Recipients.ResolveAll

    replyEmail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>insert body here</BODY></HTML>" & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.Display
    
    Set origEmail = Nothing
    Set replyEmail = Nothing
        
End Sub
```

I have two problems:

1 - When this macro is used, all the images in the new email are not showing. I'm keen to learn why this is and how to solve it.

2 - Whenever I close the email, it doesn't give me a discard option. I want the email to display and tried to add code into it to allow me to discard it but no luck.

I am going to be honest, my knowledge of VBA is limited but I am a keen learner and do my best to understand the code. I apologise in advance if I ask further questions to replies made but please be assured, these are to expand my knowledge.

Comment: You may find it useful to review the answers to the following question, where there are a few ways of handling replies mentioned. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65487474/how-to-format-outlook-message-which-is-formatted-in-plaintext

Comment: 1. Isn't this what you get with a manual reply? 2. There is no `.Close` in the code provided.

Comment: Niton - 1. I used the same code before and didn't have this issue. I am using Outlook 365, I am not sure if this is having an impact. 

2 - I added the .close clause and then you have add ol with the relevant code. I added .close oldiscard. When you click the button, it immediately discards the email. 

Apologies for my lack of understanding.

Comment: An @ prefix is required to send a message - @niton.

Comment: Change `.Reply` to `.Forward`.

Comment: @niton - Thank you for both pointers, I will try this and let you know how I get on.

Comment: @Tragamor - Apologies for my tardy reply. I've checked the link you sent but will do a deeper dive into it. There are a few things I need to get head around.